# How can I make sure a thread is completed its task,then only new Thread can start in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am getting struck how to know that a thread completed its task successfully and then only allow another thread to execute? 
    Explanation: Suppose I have 10 modules. But the thread should do task sequentially. After fully completing the request for one module then only it should jump to next module.

Below is my code:

```
SiaThread.java

Collection <Modulo> modules = mppt.getModuloCollection();
for(Module module:modules){
   UriThread threadUri = new UriThread(UriThread.URI_ENERGY_DAY,uriPath,"GET",semapore, module, gduSemapore,devType);
      UriThread threadUriFault = new UriThread (UriThread.URI_FAILURE, uriPath, "GET", semapore, module, gduSemapore,devType);
      }



UriThread.java
public UriThread (int iType, String strBaseUrl, String strmethod, Semaphore objsemaphore, Modulo module, GduSemaphore gduSemapore,String devType) {
        this.iUriType = iType;
        this.iRetry = 0;
        this.strBaseUrl = strBaseUrl; 
        this.strMethod = strmethod;
        this.semaphore = objsemaphore;
        this.gduSemapore = gduSemapore;
        this.modulo = module;
        this.strResponse = "";
        this.devType=devType;
        setState (URI_FORMATION);
        threadUrl = new Thread(this);
        threadUrl.start();
    }
```

The task needs to be done one after another,if the Thread has not completed its task,then it should wait.

```
.Here semapore=new Semapore(10,true);
```

More explanation of the question: One SiaThread is there inside which the above two threads are running. I want the SiaThread will wait to complete its task in the loop for one module and then do the task for another module in the loop. plese give me the suggestion with code so that it will be better understandable for me.

Comment: If you want two actions to be perform sequentially, you should perform them in the same thread.

Comment: Read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html . I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hello Peter Lawrey,for one module,the task can occur simultaneously, but after completion of both threads for one module,they should go to next module.

Comment: @Rasmitapatra then that is a different question.

Comment: If in case you want two or more threads to run sequentially then use thread.join(). But I hope that what you want is not all threads running sequentially but one specific thread's completion depending on the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given requirement use Thread.join(). For more advanced requirements of thread control use synchronized,wait,notify to implement a monitor; higher level api (java concurrent package) should also be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You should **join** a thread you are waiting for. You can read more at official Java docummentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html

From there: "The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing."

Answer (score 0):

Either use `Thread.join()` if you want to handle the sequencing of tasks yourself. Or have a look at `java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, which can work off tasks sequentially for you.